# Printwriter making newlines out of spaces

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a Reader reading in a file to edit it and save it afterwards with a printwriter. 
The start input is like [this](http://www.youscreen.de/yqqhpzauo71.jpg) 
The problem is, that sometimes whitespaces are mistaken for new lines somehow like [here](http://www.youscreen.de/ifhvpnlgs79.jpg). I goes even further in cutting it again after the first time
like [this](http://www.youscreen.de/ywjslcopm79.jpg)

I have tried some different split characters, like 
 (what it actually is (you can see in System.out.println)) but I can´t get it to work properly

The Original loaded Textfile is [this](https://pastebin.com/UvCwezMQ) and the output of the getText is [this](https://pastebin.com/PYsLZgdx)

```java
if (lastClicked != 0) {
                    String path;
                    switch (lastClicked) {
                    case 1:
                        path = "data/alyxia_status.got";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        path = "data/mog_status.got";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        path = "data/telias_status.got";
                        break;
                    default:
                        path = "data/tiernen_status.got";
                    }
                    String text = textPane.getText();                   
                    String toWrite = text.substring(44, text.length() - 16);
                    System.out.println(toWrite);
                    String[] parts = toWrite.split("<br>");

                    FileWriter fileWriter;
                    try {
                        fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);
                        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
                        printWriter.print(parts[0]);
                        for (int i = 1; i<parts.length; i++) {  
                            if (parts[i] != "" && parts[i] != " ") {
                                printWriter.println();                              
                                printWriter.print(parts[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        printWriter.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {                      
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        System.err.println("Saving failed");
                    }

                }//end if
```

It should just split on the string `"<br>"` and not on white spaces that are in between (in System.out.println it´s showing "Base" and then in a newline "Damage")

Comment: Maybe the newline is a real part of the original data?

Comment: When I first load the data in it´s without the newline, the newline comes in after saving it and reloading it again

Comment: The first 44 characters of the text are discarded because of your `text.substring(44, text.length() - 16);`. This includes everything up to "-- Base" (just before "Damage").

Comment: the first (and last) characters are the html tags for html, head & body, that I don´t want to be saved, but I´ll take a look at that again, if I have cutted of too much maybe

Comment: @Nova I've updated my answer to provide a complete solution to your problem. Let me know via comments if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs fine for me, try to invoke the `printToFile` method and pass your `String` array to is as a parameter. By isolating the problematic code in a separate method it should be much easier to debug. I've also noticed you are comparing `String` objects with operators, this is not advised and doesn't do what you think it does. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/5759072) for more information.

```
public static void printToFile(String path, String[] output) {

    FileWriter fileWriter;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        printWriter.print(output[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < output.length; i++)
        {
            /* DO NOT compare string with opeators like "!=" or "==,
             * instead use equals method to properly compare them
             */
            if (!output[i].equals("") && !output[i].equals(" ")) {
                printWriter.println();
                printWriter.print(output[i]);
            }
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Saving failed");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Path path = Paths.get("sample.txt");
    String[] text = new String[] { "these ", " lines ", "should", " be  ", " in   new ", "line" };

    printToFile(path.toString(), text);
    Files.readAllLines(path).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output**

```
these 
 lines 
should
 be  
 in   new 
line
```

**Edit:** What @DodgyCodeException mentioned in the comments could be the actual cause of your problem. For visibility sake I will just paste the comment:

> The first 44 characters of the text are discarded because of your text.substring(44, text.length() - 16);. This includes everything up to "-- Base" (just before "Damage").

**Complete solution**

I've written a full solution to your problem in the following code. Try the code and see if it works for you then read the explanation posted underneath the code:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * Use {@link StringBuilder} to build a single {@code String}
     * from the read contents of file located under given path.
     * 
     * @param path {@code Path} of the file to read
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs reading from the file
     *         or a malformed or unmappable byte sequence is read.
     */
    private static String getInputFileContent(Path path) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Files.readAllLines(path).forEach(sb::append);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return the matched content contained in <body> tag within
     *         the provided text or {@code null} if there was no match.
     */
    private static @Nullable String getHTMLBodyFromText(String text) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\s*?<body>)(?:\\s*)((.*\\s)*)</body>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
    }

    public static void printToFile(Path path, String output) {

        String toWrite = getHTMLBodyFromText(output);
        if (toWrite == null) {
            System.err.println("Unable to find body");
            return;
        }
        String[] parts = toWrite.split("<br>");
        FileWriter fileWriter;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(path.toString());
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
            printWriter.print(parts[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
            {
                /* DO NOT compare string with opeators like "!=" or "==,
                 * instead use equals method to properly compare them
                 */
                if (!parts[i].equals("") && !parts[i].equals(" ")) {
                    printWriter.println(parts[i]);
                    printWriter.print(parts[i]);
                }
            }
            printWriter.close();
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Saving failed");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Path inputPath = Paths.get("input.txt");
        Path outputPath = Paths.get("output.txt");

        printToFile(outputPath, getInputFileContent(inputPath));
    }
}
```

I've used `Regex` to find the text contained within the `<body>` tag of the input file you provided *(the actual content we want is located in `group 1`)* which was the part that was causing this problem. If you are further interested to see how the pattern included in this code works see this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MS8zYh/1).

The rest of your code works fine so all you have to do is call the `printToFile` method and pass the return value of `textPane.getText()` as `output` `String` argument and it will process and print the required result for you to the text file located under a path of your choosing.

Comment: I have put the code in a separate method as you advised and also swapped the operators and the problem seems to come from the string split method

Comment: Yea I think the cause of your problem comes from either `text.substring(44, text.length() - 16)` or from using the `split` operation. Can you please provide the full text that `textPane.getText()` method return and include it in your question. This way I can run the test myself and give you a complete answer as to what is the problem. Might be best to post the text on PasteBin or somewhere like that and then provide a link not to clutter the question too much.

Comment: I´ve added it now

Comment: I made it work with your solution, but it still does this weird linebreak :( oh and what is the getInputFileContent method for? I don´t have to use it to make it work löike before

Comment: Oh no you don't have to use that method it's just to read the content of a file and construct it into a single string. It is weird that you are still having the linebreak issue, I have used the same text you gave me and I don't have that problem.

Comment: Can you please create a new Java project and use only this code with the text file that contains your HTML? If that works we can then eliminate this code from being the problem.

Comment: I created a new Project and now everything is in there twice somehow, but it seems to still have the gap in there [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ue4egFg0)